# FFMPEG - Reduce frame rate etc

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, frame-rate

The below code we use to stream webcasts, its very ram hungry. We usually use PCs with 8gb of ram, however, we have a lot with only 4gb. I need some help reducing the frame rate etc.. so the machines with 4gb of ram can handle streaming and not lose their frame rate and be jumpy.

Any help would be amazing.

Video:
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -thread_queue_size 512 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2000M -audio_buffer_size 25 -framerate 25 -i video="QP0203 PCI, Analog 01 Capture":audio="Line In (2- Realtek(R) Audio)" -vcodec h264_qsv -preset veryslow -look_ahead 1 -vsync 1 -async 1 -reset_timestamps 1 -r 25 -g 25 -b:v 2M -acodec aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -ab 192k -vf format=yuv420p {{OUTPUT_FILENAME}}

Webcast(REC)
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -thread_queue_size 512 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2000M -audio_buffer_size 25 -framerate 25 -i video="QP0203 PCI, Analog 01 Capture":audio="Line In (2- Realtek(R) Audio)" -vcodec h264_qsv -preset veryslow -look_ahead 1 -vsync 1 -async 1 -reset_timestamps 1 -r 25 -g 25 -b:v 2M -acodec aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -ab 192k -vf format=yuv420p {{OUTPUT_FILENAME}}

Webcast(STREAM):
ffmpeg -hide_banner -re -i  {{OUTPUT_FILENAME}} -vcodec h264_qsv -preset slower -s 1280x720 -vsync 1 -async 1 -r 25 -b:v 650K -minrate:v 650K -maxrate:v 650K -acodec aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -ab 128k -bsf:v 'filter_units=pass_types=1-5'  -map 0 -g 50 -flags -global_header -f flv rtmp://xx.xxx.0.xx/xxxxxxxxx_live /stream

Comment: "Video" and "Webcast(REC)" commands are the same. Are you actually executing both? To literally answer the "reduce frame rate" question: reduce the `-framerate` value.

Comment: Thank you for your help. We do use both. As far as I'm aware and I could be wrong, one is for local recording while the other is for streaming. (At least that's how our software is set up)

Comment: Since it seems you are using all three commands I recommend only using #2 and #3 because #1 and #2 are exactly the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, our software demands the "video" field to be filled out. I have also tried your suggestion and lowered the -framerate value to no avail. It doesn't seem to work.